# Cannot access google play services Amazon

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, google-play-services

I am promoting my app on both Google play and Amazon store. However when the app is downloaded from Amazon store, the app is not able to access google play services and it says that app is wrongly configured. Does Amazon modify my binary when I upload it. Or there is something i have completely missed. In the logs I see following error

Works perfectly for app on Play store

Access Not Configured. Please use Google Developers Console to activate the API for your project.
Unable to sign in - application does not have a registered client ID

Cannot access google play services Amazon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The signature of the app from the android play store was somehow different from the one on play store. only needed to add that in console and link new app, with the same package name

Comment: would you mind elaborating on the steps to do it? I am having the same problem here. The explanation you gave is a bit ambiguous

Comment: Amazon modifies the signature of the app when you upload it. SO what you need to do is upload your apk to Amazon, then download from it's app store check the logs to see the signature it uses to access play services and then use that signature. This would be totally different from the signature you see locally